# KQL (Keyword not Kusto) Nesting, Document Selecting for an Extranet

Tags: sharepoint-online

Longtime member, been a  while since posting. Working on building out an Extranet and am running into a stupidly frustrating issue. First time using SharePoint Online as document repository for external (anonymous) users. In doing so, using Azure permissoning, have the documents split up in repositories on SharePoint based on access level. On top of that I am attempting to display them in Highlighted Content Web part, I am not able to sort them out by location AND type. I have a custom column in each repository that defines what type they are, but when I try to add the AND portion to the KQL it doesn't work. Additionally the internet seems to be massively void of actual documentation of KQL.

```html
(
path:https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%201%20Resources/

OR

path:https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%202%20Resources/

OR

path:https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%203%20Resources/

OR

path:https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%204%20Resources/

OR

path:https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%205%20Resources/

OR

path:https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%206%20Resources/


AND

DocType:"Articles"
)
```

The above will simply pull all documents from those locations and ignore the AND statement. I have tried renaming it to call on the custom column identifier pulled from the source, and that doesn't work either.

The only real documentation I can find on this is: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)

Which doesn't appear to address filtering based on custom column tags.

EDIT: Reformatted to pull all docs from multiple locations using below, but the nesting portion still isn't working

```html
path:(
"https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%201%20Resources/"

OR

"https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%202%20Resources/"

OR

"https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%203%20Resources/"

OR

"https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%204%20Resources/"

OR

"https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%205%20Resources/"

OR

"https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example/Level%206%20Resources/"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the additional issue I was running into was the creation of a column to separate out based on the category of file type (not literal file type). Apparently SPO doesn't like it when you create a list and then reference that list to then filter by via KQL. So I found this morning [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/408476/how-to-filter-sharepoint-online-queries-kql-docume.html).

Apparently the best way to do this is create a custom "Choice" column, allow some time for it to flow and update, and then you can reference it via KQL.